# Is it possible to use JPa and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

can use JPA and Hibernate in the same time?
in the netbeans IDE ,I can create a project by mentioning the framework used hibernate,and then create a proprities.xml files to configure the mapping!

Comment: Might be time to read up on what Hibernate is!

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to get some basic understanding of what Hibernate is first. The Java Persistence API (JPA) is a specification defined in [JSR 220](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220) and [JSR 317](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) (JPA 2.0). Hibernate is a JPA provider, i.e. Hibernate is an implementation of the JPA specification.

As a starting point you can take a look at this [JPA Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). You can find lots of Hibernate documentation online, but to get a deeper understanding of Hibernate I strongly recommend to read the book [Java Persistence with Hibernate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394885).